# How can you access an sqlalchemy table column using jinja with variable

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose I used SQLAlchemy to create a table that looks like:

```
Table
+----+------+------+------+-----+
| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | foo | ...
+----+------+------+------+-----+
|  1 |  a   |  b   |  c   | bar | ...
+----+------+------+------+-----+
   .
   .
   .
```

I am using python flask to render a html template.

Say I pass a row of this table to my html template using flask's `render_template` method.

`return render_template('foo'.html, row=Table.query.filter_by(id=1).first())`

Then in `foo.html` I want to loop over this row and access the values from each of the columns that are begin with `col`.

In other words I want to access `a,b,c` only but not `bar`.

I have tried:

```
{% for i in range(1,3) %}
  {{ row.coli }}   
{% endfor %}
```

However this doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi I tried adding `{{ getattr(row, 'col' + str(i)) }}` but got an error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str' is undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the columns, you might as well just use them, i.e. write `{{ row.Col1 }}`, then `{{ row.Col2}}`, etc. (and if using Core, `{{ row.c.Col1 }}`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because col1,col2 are not arrays, they are just column name in sql.

Comment: Can you offer an solution since this is not possible

Comment: I have given a solution. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
row = Table.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
return render_template('foo.html', row=row)
```

in HTML use this:

```
{{row.col1}} <!--Output : a -->
{{row.col2}} <!--Output : b -->
{{row.col3}} <!--Output : c -->
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying, you could simply do this:

```
{% for i in row %}
  {{ i.col1 }}{{ i.col2 }}{{ i.col3 }}   
{% endfor %}
```